# Local storage to change background colour

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to change the background colour of my website with local storage. I am using `onchange()` within the HTML for the `colours()` function, and the rest is the JavaScript below

```
var bgcolour;

window.onload = function theme(){

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    localStorage.setItem("bgcolour", 1);
}


function colours(){
    localStorage.bgcolour = document.getElementById("party").value;

    if (localStorage.bgcolour == '1'){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

It does nothing. It doesn't even change, let alone store it as local storage.

I keep missing vital, small parts of code and it feels like I have done it again with this one.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
 <select name="pnumber" id="party" onchange="colours()">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
     <option value="10">10</option>
     <option value="11">11</option>
     <option value="12">12</option>
     <option value="13">13</option>
     <option value="14">14</option>
     <option value="15">15 (maximum)</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is wrong, you are improperly setting and checking localStorage values. Also, you need to get the value from the node with id party.

```js
var bgcolour;

window.onload = function theme(){

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    localStorage.setItem("bgcolour", 1);
}

var party = document.getElementById('party')
function colours(){
 
    localStorage.setItem('bgcolour', party.value);

    if (localStorage.getItem('bgcolour') === '1'){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  else{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="pnumber" id="party" onchange="colours()">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
     <option value="10">10</option>
     <option value="11">11</option>
     <option value="12">12</option>
     <option value="13">13</option>
     <option value="14">14</option>
     <option value="15">15 (maximum)</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I can't even get it to work across multiple pages yet, and this code is a bit over my head, but thank you anyway!

Comment: I know, however, I don't believe you will be able to achieve what you set out to do without doing it this way.  Let me know if you want clarification or extra help

Comment: Other people (this is for class) have achieved it with quite simple code, and mine *looks* similar but I am clearly missing something. It's so frustrating.

At the very least, I need to be able to do it without using event listeners.

Comment: your code is wrong, you are not setting localStorage correctly on your function

Comment: That is why I am here :). Could you please tell me how to correctly set it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Now any value changes the background colour to red (I have values of 1-15) and it still will not work on multiple pages

Comment: you should post your whole code including HTML.It is likely you are making mistakes in other places

Comment: I have included the relevant HTML. The JS code is already fully posted.

Comment: The answer has been updated. I set the default to green. since the other numbers do not have a color associated with them.

Comment: This works fantastically, thank you ever so much! The only slight issue with it is that is does not change instantaniously - so the default colour is briefly visible, but that is a negligible problem!!

Comment: @Matt you should select the answer if it helped solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<button class = 'w3-button w3-red w3-hover-black w3-btn' onclick = "setBackground('#e60000')">Red</button>
<button class = 'w3-button w3-blue w3-hover-black w3-btn' onclick = "setBackground('#004de6')">Blue</button>
<button class = 'w3-button w3-green w3-hover-black w3-btn' onclick = "setBackground('#00802b')">Green</button>
<button class = 'w3-button w3-yellow w3-hover-black w3-btn' onclick = "setBackground('#e6e600')">Yellow</button>

<script>
function setBackground(color) 
{
  localStorage.setItem("name", color);
  window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Ritabrata/localStorage.html';  //reload the page to effect the change.
}

if(localStorage.name)   //Accessing name variable of localStorage.
{
  document.body.style.background = localStorage.name;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some issues with setting and getting values from local-storage. Below is how it is done.

// Store

`localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");`

// Retrieve

`document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");`

Comment: That doesn't really help. I saw exactly that on W3, and it has nothing to do with obtaining and changing background colour values, nor does it explain how I should implement it.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to accomplish here. Do you want to set the background-color to red and change when an event occurs. Please explain more your need.

Comment: I want to change the background colour of my website, and by using localstorage, enable the background colour to stay changed.

Comment: to stay unchanged or change to a different colour?

Comment: To change and remain changed when I click to another page or refresh my current page

Answer (score 0):

I believe something is wrong with your HTML. [See this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/eUj1U898HdX0lw6uTFyG?p=preview). I copy pasted all of your javascript and I'm assuming your HTML is something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="party" onchange="colours()" />
```

You will notice that the background is originally gray, then putting a value "1" in the textbox will make the background red.

Comment: My html is exactly like that and it doesn't work.

EDIT. I lie.Here it is <select name="party number" id="party" onchange="colours()">

Comment: See updated plunk, I changed it to the select dropdown. Note that local storage is a bit weird on plnkr so you'll have to try it on your platform.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a whirl!

Comment: I take back my comment on that plnkr has weird local storage. See updated plunk: you have to check and change your background color dependent on localstorage upon pageload

Comment: Huh? That doesn't make any sense

Comment: What doesn't make sense? The logic or the english? See the updated plunk and you'll understand.

Comment: It must be my HTML, or some interference elsewhere. It will not do anything at all still and I cannot work out why! D:

Comment: I can't help you without your HTML and platform. Does the plunk have your desired behavior?